# What are the Shulker's capabilities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I haven't really played Minecraft recently, but when I did get on for a bit, I tried out 1.9. I mostly just fooled around with the Shulker. All it seemed to do was act like a purple clam and shoot homing missiles at you, which made you levitate. Is there anything I missed that the Shulker can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also teleport if you break the block it will attach too. It will also try to teleport if it has less than half his health. You can check the Minecraft Wiki here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shulker if want to read more about it.

Comment: @camelCase Thanks for clearing that up. Will make sure to remember to do that in the future!

Comment: I believe they are the only block that moves up and down, so if you stand on them you will bop!